# How does the view in the app get the parameters in the urls.py under the project？

Tags: python, django

My directory structure(omit other unnecessary files):

```
root
  urls.py
app
  urls.py
  views.py
```

root/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:_key>', include('app.urls'))
]
```

app/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.my_view, name="my_view"),
]
```

app/views.py

```
def my_view(request, key):
    res = my_func(key)

    return HttpResponse(res)
```

Then my_view cannot get the parameter key, my url is `http://localhost:8000/hU7B9T`

Comment: i think its because the key u r passing into root url , not in the app url

Comment: yea , so switch. root url : '' , app url :'<slug:_key>'

Comment: No, this still won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply some changes:
1.- use slug in app urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:key>/', views.my_view, name="my_view"),
]
```

2.- dont know what my_func(key) is doing..., but views.py can be like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def my_view(request, key):
    

    return HttpResponse(key)
```

3.- then, when you go to this url: http://localhost:8000/hU7B9T/  the slug is passed to the view and used in HttpREsponse

4.- You can use this urls.py in the main dir:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]
```